# Netty Eventloop blocked on `keventWait`

Tags: java, performance, netty

I am using netty's event loop to `submit` callables and runnables in my program and sometimes they never get executed. When I take a thread dump it looks kind of like this —

```
io.netty.channel.kqueue.Native.keventWait(int, long, int, long, int, int, int)
io.netty.channel.kqueue.Native.keventWait(int, io.netty.channel.kqueue.KQueueEventArray, io.netty.channel.kqueue.KQueueEventArray, int, int) (line: 113)
io.netty.channel.kqueue.KQueueEventLoop.kqueueWait(int, int) (line: 177)
io.netty.channel.kqueue.KQueueEventLoop.kqueueWait(boolean) (line: 169)
io.netty.channel.kqueue.KQueueEventLoop.run() (line: 238)
io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run() (line: 986)
io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run() (line: 74)
io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run() (line: 30)
java.lang.Thread.run() (line: 834)
```

Basically netty is waiting for events forever without any timeout. What is the right way to handle this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

This should not happen and if so it is a bug. Please upgrade to the latest netty version and if this still happens open a bug report on our issue tracker with all the needed infos.